# O PyQT5 monitora os eventos de forma Assíncrona no Windows e Síncrona no Raspberry?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, pyqt

### **Contexto**

Estou desenvolvendo um programa que usa o OpenCV4 pra identificar alguns fixadores de metal, o programa é relativamente simples e usa em suma filtros de contorno de busca por cores, no Windows até então tudo roda como o desejado, porém tenho que fazer a portabilidade para o RaspBerry Pi3, depois de alguns dias resolvendo problemas de instalação do Python3.9, Opencv4.4 e o PYQT5, consegui fazer o código rodar e exibir a tela principal da aplicação, e as demais 'normalmente'.

---

### **Problema**

No Windows, quando defino um gatilho que aciona uma função na classe em que estou, ele SEMPRE pode ser acionado, não importa se a função que esta rodando está em um 'while', 'sleep', 'for' ou qualquer outra coisa, então quando eu clico no botão 'Start' ele aciona a função 'onClicked()' que se mantem em um 'while' atualizando a imagem com o 'displayImage()', mas caso eu clique, por exemplo, no botão 'Stop' ele passa pra função 'OnClicked' o paramentro 'False' que quebra o 'while'. (Provavelmente não é o melhor jeito de se fazer, mas funciona).

No RaspBerry quando a minha função 'onCliked()' é acionada e entra dentro do 'while' todo o resto do programa para de responder, como se o eventos não fossem mais monitorados, mas não entendo o porque isso acontece, o código é o mesmo, o funcionamento deveria ser o mesmo certo?. Como faço os eventos serem monitorados a todo momento no RaspBerry?.

Como o código é grande tive que cortar algumas partes, mas vocês podem ver o completo no meu [repositório](https://github.com/Sherensberk/CEO96F/tree/RaspPortable).

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    # Define o LayOut e a(s) ação(es) de cada gatilho(s).
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("Ui/mainWindow.ui", self)
        self.PhotoPath.setText(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../Images/')))
        # Associando as classes de outras janelas a um objeto correspondente.
        self.JsonWindow = JsonTree()
        self.ControllerWindow = MachineController()
        self.PopUpWindow = PopUp()

        # Conecta o botão de inicio á execução do programa de identificação.
        self.Start.clicked.connect(
            lambda checked: self.onClicked(True)
        )

        # Conecta o botão de Saida com a função que finaliza a execução do programa.
        self.Stop.clicked.connect(
            lambda checked: self.onClicked(False)
        )
```

Função que é chamada quando aperto o botão "Iniciar".  (Cortei alguns pedaços pra postar aqui)

```
    def onClicked(self, FDs):
    global cap, img, nominalIndex, Processo
    Processo = FDs
    if Processo:
        last = self.janela

    # Mantem o processo rodando.
    while Processo:

            lower = np.array([
                self.h_min.value(),
                self.s_min.value(),
                self.v_min.value()
            ])
            upper = np.array([
                self.h_max.value(),
                self.s_max.value(),
                self.v_max.value()
            ])
            msk = Op.refineMask(Op.HSVMask(edge_analyze, lower, upper))
            cv2.rectangle(msk, (0, 0), (msk.shape[1], msk.shape[0]), (0, 0, 0), thickness=20)
            chr_k = cv2.bitwise_and(edge_analyze, edge_analyze, mask=msk)

       
        self.displayImage(chr_k, 1)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

---

Função responsável por exibir a imagem no meu 'QLabel'.  (Cortei alguns pedaços pra postar aqui)

```
    def displayImage(self, imgs, window=1):
        qformat = QImage.Format_Indexed8
        if self.janela == zProcess and not self.LiveS.isChecked():
            imgs = cv2.resize(imgs, None, fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
        if len(imgs.shape) == 3:
            if (imgs.shape[2]) == 4:
                qformat = QImage.Format_RGBA888
            else:
                qformat = QImage.Format_RGB888
        imgs = QImage(imgs, imgs.shape[1], imgs.shape[0], qformat)
        imgs = imgs.rgbSwapped()
        self.imgLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(imgs))
        self.imgLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
```

---

### Demonstração de Funcionamento em ambos os Sistemas:

*Raspberry Pi3 com o SO padrão de 2021:*
[image: Raspberry para de responder após a imagem ser exibida]

---

*Windows 10:*
[image: Programa não trava no Windows]

Essa é a minha primeira pergunta feita aqui no STOF, então caso algo não tenha ficado claro ou possa melhorar por favor avisem.

Comment: Olá @Henrycke B.S, sei que a pergunta já foi feita há algum tempo, mas apenas para explicar: o que aconteceu aqui é que você precisa executar toda a lógica da função `onClicked` em uma thread separada, caso contrário a thread em que a interface está rodando é bloqueada por essa função e a interface deixa de ficar responsiva. Isso é verdade tanto para Windows quanto para Raspberry Pi (ou qualquer outro SO). O que deve ter acontecido é que em Windows a execução é rápida o suficiente para você não notar o programa deixando de ficar responsivo.

Comment: Humm, não tinha levado em consideração a velocidade do processamento, acho estranho ficar tão discrepante mas faz sentido, de todo modo, acabei separando esse e outros processos em outras threads e funcionou "bem" infelizmente comecei a ter problemas com "falha de segmentação" no raspberry, e resolvi mudar a interface toda pra web logo. Agradeço a atenção @jfaccioni <3